# D3.js how to make the lines not go inside the arc of a donut chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to make a donut chart with text labels as per this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799):

[image: donut chart]

However, I dont want the lines to enter into the inner area of the arc. I just want them to touch the circumference of the arc without entering it.

Does D3.js provide any ready made functions to find out the center of the arc circumference or is there any other way using SVG to modify the lines.

Comment: Please share a code attempt or any code sample you tried for same.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the easiest way will be to rearrange the order of the elements. Because SVGs elements will be drawn in document order this will have the effect of elements being rendered *on top* of other elements which they succeed. The example uses three groups to arrange the slices, the text labels and the lines.

```
svg.append("g").attr("class", "slices");   // 1.
svg.append("g").attr("class", "labels");   // 2.
svg.append("g").attr("class", "lines");    // 3.
```

By putting the `<g>` for the slices to the end this will cover part of the lines giving the look like they ended on the outer arc of the slices.

```
svg.append("g").attr("class", "labels");   // 2.
svg.append("g").attr("class", "lines");    // 3.
svg.append("g").attr("class", "slices");   // 1.
```

There is no need for further adjustements. Have a look at this [working example](http://blockbuilder.org/altocumulus/5adf28e7b13447b8a1e309ed98fcb07a).